# PDO refuses to switch between multiple Databases!

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, pdo, mysql-error-1146

Please I am very new to PDO, rather a novice at PHP as well. I am currently working on a project that involves connections to many databases: MySQL, MSSQL and Oracle. So I am using the class below, with PDO, for my connection. The class code is below.

`class db {`

```
private static $objInstance;

/*
 * Class Constructor - Create a new database connection if one doesn't exist
 * Set to private so no-one can create a new instance via ' = new DB();'
 */
private function __construct() {}

/*
 * Like the constructor, we make __clone private so nobody can clone the instance
 */
private function __clone() {}

/*
 * Returns DB instance or create initial connection
 * @param
 * @return $objInstance;
 */
public static function getDB($DBtype, $DBindex) {

    include('vars.inc.php');

    if (!self::$objInstance){
        $DBid = $DBindex - 1;
        switch ($DBtype){
            case "mysql":
                self::$objInstance = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbvars[$DBid][0].";dbname=".$dbvars[$DBid][1], $dbvars[$DBid][2], $dbvars[$DBid][3]);
                break;
            case "mssql":
                self::$objInstance = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=".$dbvars[$DBid][0].";Database=".$dbvars[$DBid][1], $dbvars[$DBid][2], $dbvars[$DBid][3]);
                break;
            case "oci";
                self::$objInstance = new PDO("oci:dbname=//".$dbvars[$DBid][0].":".$dbvars[$DBid][4]."/".$dbvars[$DBid][1], $dbvars[$DBid][2], $dbvars[$DBid][3]);
                break;
            // Add other case(s) here if another RDBMS (Relational Database Management system) is used
            default:
                break;
        }
        self::$objInstance-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    return self::$objInstance;      

}
```

}

And here is the vars include file that is required by the class, I used an array cos I felt this way, new databases can be added easily to the vars file by a non-programmer over time. Of course, here, I have changed the var file values.

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'db1name');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'rootpass');
define('DB_PORT', '');

define('DB2_SERVER', 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx');
define('DB2_NAME', 'db2name');
define('DB2_USER', 'root2');
define('DB2_PASSWORD', 'rootpass2');
define('DB2_PORT', '');

define('DB3_SERVER', 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
define('DB3_NAME', db3name');
define('DB3_USER', 'root3');
define('DB3_PASSWORD', 'rootpass3');
define('DB3_PORT', '');

define('DB4_SERVER', 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx');
define('DB4_NAME', 'oracledb');
define('DB4_USER', 'root4');
define('DB4_PASSWORD', 'rootpass4');
define('DB4_PORT', '1521');

$dbvars = array( array(DB_SERVER, DB_NAME , DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_PORT),
               array(DB2_SERVER, DB2_NAME , DB2_USER, DB2_PASSWORD, DB2_PORT),
               array(DB3_SERVER, DB3_NAME , DB3_USER, DB3_PASSWORD, DB3_PORT),
               array(DB4_SERVER, DB4_NAME , DB4_USER, DB4_PASSWORD, DB4_PORT)               
             );
```

Now the problem is that, whenever I have connected to one database and try to run my queries on another one, PDO keeps remembering the old database. But if I independently run either query, everything is fine. Can someone please help with this, or suggest a better method? :(

E.g.

`include('./includes/db.class.php');
    try {
        $result = DB::getDB("mysql", 3)->query("SELECT myrow FROM mytable");`

```
    foreach($result as $row){
        print $row['myrow'].'<br />';
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo "<br />Then<br /><hr /><br />";
try {
    $result = DB::getDB("mysql", 1)->query("SELECT yourrow FROM yourtable");

    foreach($result as $row){
        print $row['yourrow'].'<br />' ;
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

*In this case, PDO will simply keep checking DATABASE db1name for TABLE yourtable rather than check DATABASE db3name. So PDO will throw an error:

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db1name.yourtable' doesn't exist***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it setup as a singleton.  So your next call to `Db::getDB` returns the original instance.  If you want to cache the instances for the duration of the script, change `$objInstance` to an array, and then instead of doing:

```
if (!self::$objInstance){
```

Do

```
$signature = $DBtype . $DBindex;
if (!isset(self::$objInstances[$signature])) {
```

Of course you'll need to change the assignment lines and the return line as well, but I think you get the idea...

Comment: Thanks, ircmaxell. I think this may work, but right now it declares, referencing that code I just added:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDO as array in C:\apache\htdocs\ticabo\includes\db.class.php on line 29

Comment: As I said, you'll need to change the assignment lines as well (and the return line).  So instead of doing `self::$objInstances = new...` and `return self::$objInstances;`, you'll need to do `self::$objInstances[$signature] = new...` and `return self::$objInstances[$signature]` respectively...

Comment: Yay!!! It worked like magic!!! Thanks!!!! You're the man! Now I really need to learn OOP. :-)

Comment: Well, that's not really OOP.  That's just storing things in an array dynamically...  But glad I could help...

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your getDB function will only connect once because of this line:

```
if (!self::$objInstance){
```

So the first time you execute it, it will connect, but on all subsequent calls the logic is ignored.

I suggest adding another property to your class that stores the current DBType and changing your conditional to:

```
if (!self::$objInstance || $DBtype != self::$dbtype){
```

You would have to set $dbtype inside each case of the switch statement.

Comment: Thanks Fosco! Let me try to remove that line and see how it goes :)

Comment: Great idea, Fosco. The only problem is that the DBtype doesnt distinguish the DB :( I am working with many MySQL DBs and some MSSQL ones and an Oracle one. More may also be added later...

Comment: ok then some combination of dbtype and dbindex?... you get the idea, though, right?

Comment: Yes, Fosco! I get the idea. Im very grateful for the help. Ircmaxwell gave a similar suggestion, combining dbtype and dbindex :) The only problem is that I cant quite wrap around the PDO object / array stuff yet (I know very little OOP as at now). Thanks again.